# How to parse one response in json?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, zimbra

I am getting the response of a SearchRequest I'm doing to zimbra.

How would it be possible to have the unread emails?

in this case represented by `u:1` unread and read by `u:0`

This is an example of the response I get alert

```
var response = result.getResponse();
alert(response.toSource());
```

this is what goes on alert.

```
({SearchResponse:{sortBy:"dateDesc", offset:0, c:[{id:"-441", u:1, n:1, f:"u", d:1439699427000, su:"Daily mail report for 2015-08-15", fr:"Grand Totals -- messages 1 received 2 delivered 0 forwarded 1 deferred (5 deferrals) 0 bounced 0 rejected (0%) 0 reject warnings 0 held 0 discarded ...", e:[{a:"admin@localhost.local", d:"admin", t:"f"}], m:[{id:"441", s:"5103", l:"300", f:"u"}], sf:"1439699427000"}, {id:"314", u:0, n:2, f:"s", d:1438663876000, su:"lokitox", fr:"lex", e:[{a:"admin@localhost.local", d:"admin", t:"f"}], m:[{id:"313", l:"300"}, {id:"312", l:"5", f:"s"}], sf:"1438663876000"}, {id:"-309", u:0, n:1, d:1438662639000, su:"Daily mail report for 2015-08-03", fr:"Grand Totals -- messages 91 received 117 delivered 0 forwarded 134 deferred (134 deferrals) 169 bounced 0 rejected (0%) 0 reject warnings 0 held 0 ...", e:[{a:"admin@localhost.local", d:"admin", t:"f"}], m:[{id:"309", s:"7232", l:"300"}], sf:"1438662639000"}], more:false, _jsns:"urn:zimbraMail"}})
```

I would like to put in a variable, the count of unread emails.

I imagine that count (), but not sure how to do it in pure javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one , This one will iterate through your objects , and the loops will find all unread keys and print all the values of the unread keys.

```
for(var k in response){

    for(var r in response[k].c){

        console.log(response[k].c[r].u);
    }
}
```